# SHP opening : datastore DataStoreFactorySpi is not an ImageIO SPI class

Tags: java, shapefile, javax.imageio, java-9, datastore

At school I have to create an API in which I need some geometry inside a shapefile. 
I use the geotools librairie to open the shapefile. 
Here is my code :

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String filepath = "SHP_test/testSHPindex.shp";
        File shp = new File(filepath);

        Map<String, URL> map = new HashMap<String, URL>();
        map.put( "url", shp.toURI().toURL() );
        DataStore dataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(map);


        SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = dataStore.getFeatureSource(dataStore.getTypeNames()[0]);        
        SimpleFeatureCollection collection = featureSource.getFeatures();


}
```

I obtain this mistake :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.geotools.data.DataStoreFactorySpi is not an ImageIO SPI class
    at java.desktop/javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry.checkClassAllowed(ServiceRegistry.java:745)
    at java.desktop/javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry.<init>(ServiceRegistry.java:140)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.<init>(FactoryRegistry.java:155)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryCreator.<init>(FactoryCreator.java:91)
    at org.geotools.data.DataStoreFinder.getServiceRegistry(DataStoreFinder.java:128)
    at org.geotools.data.DataStoreFinder.getAvailableDataStores(DataStoreFinder.java:115)
    at org.geotools.data.DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(DataStoreFinder.java:87)
    at org.ensg.projetperso.llb.maven.api.spatialindexingtest.testshapefile.main.main(main.java:30)
```

The datastore does not want to be created and I don't understand where does it come from ... 
Can you help me please ? 
Thanks in advance ..

Laure

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be a known issue in GeoTools, see [FactoryRegistry Refactoring for Java 9 Compatibility](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/wiki/FactoryRegistry-Refactoring-for-Java-9-Compatibility). From the issue:

> TL;DR: `org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry` extends `javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry`, but on Java 9 the latter throws an exception if extended by non-JDK classes; this breaks GeoTools on Java 9

You need to either upgrade your GeoTools version to one that is Java 9 compatible (preferred), or "downgrade" your Java to Java 8.

Comment: Right, GeoTools needs to be changed to use ServiceLoader.

Comment: what is the latest version of GeoTools - where can I Find this? I"m getting the same error